# Strcmp not working properly php

Tags: php, html

```
    <?php
        $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "","nets") or die("Couldn't connect to database");        
        $query = mysqli_query($connect,"SHOW columns FROM users");
          while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
                if( (strcmp($row['Field'],"Name") !== 0) ||
                    (strcmp($row['Field'],"ID") !== 0)||
                    (strcmp($row['Field'],"Password") !== 0)||
                    (strcmp($row['Field'],"Email") !== 0)||
                    (strcmp($row['Field'],"Company") !== 0)||
                    (strcmp($row['Field'],"Gender") !== 0)||
                    (strcmp($row['Field'],"Citizen") !== 0)){
            ?>
            <input type="radio" name="admin" value="'$row'"> 
                <?php
                    echo $row['Field'];
                    }
                ?>
                <br/>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
```

Please suggest how to skip the "Name", "ID", "Password", "Email", "Company", "Gender", "Citizen" rows and print the rest of them.

Comment: You could define an array of those and do `if(!in_array($row['Field'], $array))` but what doesn't `echo $row['Field'];` show when you run that and it doesn't work?

Comment: The output is all the rows including the one's that I have put for check. Am I missing something while writing the code ?

Comment: You need to `echo $row['Field'];` and see what it is, but I would just use either the array thing I posted above or: `if($row['Field'] != "Name")`

Comment: I have already echo the values and the values are correct and even the comaprison is providing correct output but still I see all the fields being printed.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `&&` in your code? Because even if one field doesn't match it will print the radio button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of fetching all columns and applying PHP if condition, it will be better if you fetch only the required columns.

Try this query:

```
SHOW columns FROM users WHERE field NOT IN ('Name', 'ID', 'Password', 'Email', 'Company', 'Gender', 'Citizen')
```

Comment: Be ready for the _that's great but that is simplified code, I have 14 `elseif`s   that check other columns and do other things so I need them all_

Comment: Bravo!  You escaped the hell!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to modify your code too much, then I think you just have to change `||` to `&&` because your code will currently print a radio button if even one field doesn't match.

Like this:

```
 <?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "","nets") or die("Couldn't connect to database");        
$query = mysqli_query($connect,"SHOW columns FROM users");
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        if( (strcmp($row['Field'],"Name") !== 0) &&
            (strcmp($row['Field'],"ID") !== 0) &&
            (strcmp($row['Field'],"Password") !== 0) &&
            (strcmp($row['Field'],"Email") !== 0) &&
            (strcmp($row['Field'],"Company") !== 0) &&
            (strcmp($row['Field'],"Gender") !== 0) &&
            (strcmp($row['Field'],"Citizen") !== 0)){
        ?>
        <input type="radio" name="admin" value="'$row'"> 
          <?php
              echo $row['Field'];
        }
        ?>
        <br/>
<?php
}
?>
```